# programmatically generate `d` from `p` and `q` (RSA)

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have two numbers, `p`, and `q`. I know that I can get `phi = (p-1)*(q-1)` and that `ed = 1 (mod phi)`... but I'm not sure I get what this means.

I wrote some Python:

```
p = NUM
q = NUM
e = NUM
phi = (p-1)*(q-1)
d = (1 % phi)/float(e)
```

But I always get a decimal, and `d` is supposed to be an integer. what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I may just not understand RSA. Right now, I'm looking at this page: http://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html

Comment: `(1 mode phi)` ? this is not valid Python - do you mean `(1 % phi)` ?

Comment: @jsbueno my apologies, yes. I mistyped.

Comment: @tekknolagi: You can always edit your question. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding of the math is wrong. The equation

> *ed* ≡ 1 (mod *φ*)

means that, the remainder of number *ed* dividing *φ* is equal to 1, i.e. in terms of Python,

```
>>> (e*d) % phi
1
```

For instance, if *φ* = (7 - 1)(11 - 1) = 60, and *e* = 17, then if we choose *d* = 53, then we'll get

```
>>> e = 17
>>> d = 53
>>> phi = 60
>>> (e*d) % phi
1
```

We call *d* a modular multiplicative inverse of *e*.

To generate *d* from *e* and *φ*, usually extended Euclidean algorithm is used. Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+%22multiplicative+inverse%22&submit=search for more info

Comment: So if I'm understanding this, then I have to find `gcd(e, phi)`, right?

Comment: I get `1L` - what does that mean?

Comment: @tekknolagi: A long integer with value 1. (You could post a new question.)

Comment: @GregS what is the third argument to `pow`?

Comment: My previous comment was WRONG (and now deleted). You would only get 1L if you were using the Euclidean algorithm. WRONG ALGORITHM. You need to use the [extended euclidean algorithm](http://en.literateprograms.org/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm_(Python)).

Answer (score 0):

Since the dnominator on the division is a float, Python will always promote the result of the division to a float.

If you want to explictely have the result as an integer, do not promote any of the operators to float, and use the "//" operator instead - it prevents, in a "future compatible" way, automatic conversion of the division result to a float.

`d = (1 % phi)// e`

Answer (score -1):

It's returning a decimal because you're dividing by a floating point number

```
float(e)
```

You can get the final number to be converted into an integer by wrapping the whole computation in an int() function like this :

```
d = int( (1 mod phi)/float(e) )
```

Comment: that will be `0`, since `1 % big_number == 1` and then `int(1/other number) == 0`