# using Perl Crypt::RSA but getting `Incomplete key` on attempted decryption

Tags: perl, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am trying to use `Crypt::RSA` to decrypt a message (I was given `n`, which I then factored into `p` and `q`, and I was also given `e`. I computed `d`. [programmatically generate `d` from `p` and `q` (RSA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884076/programmatically-generate-d-from-p-and-q-rsa)) but am having some difficulties. Every time I run the following code, I get `Incomplete key.`

It's such an unhelpful error message.

```
use Crypt::RSA;

my $rsa = new Crypt::RSA;

my $privkey = bless( {
    'p' => 'NUMBER',                                                                                        
    'q' => 'NUMBER',        
    'n' => 'NUMBER',
    'Version' => '1.99',
    'Identity' => '<email>' #put your email here?                                                                                                         
                     }, 'Crypt::RSA::Key::Private' );

my $plaintext = $rsa->decrypt (
    Cyphertext => "- -----BEGIN COMPRESSED RSA ENCRYPTED MESSAGE-----                                                                                                      
Version: 1.99                                                                                                                                                              
Scheme: Crypt::RSA::ES::OAEP                                                                                                                                               

block_message_here

- -----END COMPRESSED RSA ENCRYPTED MESSAGE-----",
    Key        => $privkey,
    Armour     => 1,
    ) or die $rsa->errstr();

print $plaintext;
```

Comment: according to the source code you need to supply *either* 1) n and d, *or* 2) n, p, and, q.

Comment: @GregS just provided `n`, `p`, `q` and still "Incomplete key."

Comment: Maybe you provided them in the wrong format. The relevant line of code from Private.pm is `return $self->error ("Incomplete key.") unless ($self->n && $self->d) || ($self->n && $self->p && $self->q);`